# How to code multiple "Or" in Visual Basic?

Tags: vb.net, textbox, logic

I heard VB gets confused with multiple logical operators at once, so I'm stuck here. I have 3 textboxes and I want to check if any of them is empty.

This simple If did not work:

```
If txt1.Text = "" Or txt2.Text = "" Or txt3.Text = "" Then -Something-
```

However it works if I only put two of them to compare.

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code above should work but check for null or empty string with
  String.IsNullOrEmpty is more elegant:

```
 If String.IsNullOrEmpty(txt1.Text) Or _
   String.IsNullOrEmpty(txt2.Text) Or _
   String.IsNullOrEmpty(txt3.Text) Then
        'Do something
    End If
```

PD: If you use several "OR", all the conditionals will be checked.

If you use OrElse, it will check the conditionals in order and when one it's not true
the next conditional statements will not be checked

Comment: This might work, looks logical, but I did the same thing (with string.IsNull... also) only that I put everything in the same line, no "Or _", but it didn't work.

Comment: I have just checked this code and it works for me. Don use string.IsNull use String.IsNullOrEmpty because "" is not null. Paste full code maybe I can find something

Comment: @CarlosLange Yes I used "String.IsNullOrEmpty" didn't even know any other exist. I'll test your version when I get back home later today. Does it matter if statement is written in multiple or single rows?

Comment: `Public Sub FunkcijaDatum()

        If InputDan.Text < "1" Or InputDan.Text > "31" Then Opozorilo.Text = "Dan je neveljaven!" Else Opozorilo.Text = ""
        If InputDan.Text = "" Then Opozorilo.Text = ""       
        
        If Opozorilo.Text = "Dan je neveljaven!" Then BtnGenerateLAN.Enabled = False
        If InputDan.Text = "" OrElse InputMesec.Text = "" And InputMesec.Text = "" OrElse InputLeto.Text = "" Then BtnGenerateLAN.Enabled = False Else BtnGenerateLAN.Enabled = True        
    End Sub`

The first part checks input for date - day.

Comment: @Alex it doesn't matter the _ and new line is just to read it cleaner

Answer (score 3):

For or it's not confused. The above works fine.

Comment: Well I want to disable the button if any box is empty but when I put text in first two boxes it enables it, even if third is still empty, so it doesn't check the second "Or" or something.

Comment: Then check the values. Maybe Nothing but not empty string.

Comment: @Aksen I don't quite understand you with the last one.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works. If you want the rest of the check to be ommitted you can use OrElse

```
  If txt1.Text = "" OrElse txt2.Text = "" OrElse txt3.Text = "" Then 

  End If
```

or better

```
  If String.IsNullOrEmpty(txt1.Text) OrElse String.IsNullOrEmpty(txt2.Text) OrElse String.IsNullOrEmpty(txt3.Text) Then 

  End If
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it when I get home.

Comment: An additional info: This is what we call `ShortCircuit`

Comment: Probably use `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` or `Trim()` on the text or debug your code and see what is happening. I have tested your original code and it worked

Comment: @codingbiz Can you try to make 3 textboxes and a button which will enable after you fill the textboxes? It doens't work for me that way.